# Como aumentar a largura do border-bottom?

Tags: html5, css3

- Como aumentar o `border-bottom` até onde a seta aponta :
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```css
.container__transacoes > h3{  
border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb; /*Ver como aumentar as bordas*/
padding-bottom: 10px;
margin: 30px 0px 10px;
margin-right: 190px;
}
.transacoes{
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 40px;
}
.transacoes li {
background-color: #fff;
box-shadow: var(--box-shadow);
color: #333;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
position: relative;
padding: 10px;
margin: 10px 0;
}
.transacoes li.plus {
border-right: 5px solid #0EC206;
}
  
.transacoes li.minus {
border-right: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container__transacoes">

<h3>Transações</h3>

<ul id="transacoes" class="transacoes"></ul>

<h3>Adicionar Transações</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Não é só colocar `border-bottom: 10px solid #bbb; `? ou `border-bottom-width: 15px`? Você define o tamanho o em pixel, como desejar...

Comment: Eu meio que perguntei errado , não era para aumentar a largura , e sim o tamanho dele ate onde a seta está apontando , você pode me ajudar ?

Comment: Ok. Reabri a pergunta. Mas sugiro que edite o título, pra ficar mais descritivo.

Comment: Eu dei uma ajuda na edição. O que tem no `.container_transacoes`? Acho que pode ser a resposta pra descobrir porque não vai até o final. Sugiro que cole o trecho do CSS dessa div.

Comment: Alterei aqui ,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara não está indo até o final pq vc colocou um `margin-right` de `190px` no `H3`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Da forma como está o `H3` ocupa a linha inteira, menos a largura desse `margin` ai, basta remove-lo para ficar 100%

```css
.container__transacoes > h3{  
border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb; /*Ver como aumentar as bordas*/
padding-bottom: 10px;
margin: 30px 0px 10px;
/* margin-right: 190px; */
}
.transacoes{
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 40px;
}
.transacoes li {
background-color: #fff;
box-shadow: var(--box-shadow);
color: #333;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
position: relative;
padding: 10px;
margin: 10px 0;
}
.transacoes li.plus {
border-right: 5px solid #0EC206;
}
  
.transacoes li.minus {
border-right: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container__transacoes">

<h3>Transações</h3>

<ul id="transacoes" class="transacoes"></ul>

<h3>Adicionar Transações</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado Hugo :)   , Coloquei o Width:100% ae ficou tudo certo , fico triste em saber que sua resposta foi boa e ainda deram deslike nela , deveria ter no stackOverFlow um mecanismo que pode-se denunciar pessoas que deram deslike sem motivo nenhum

Comment: @ValdenirsonPEREIRA não tem problema, o voto negativo nada muda, fico feliz em ter ajudado, vc aceitou a resposta, e eu sei que ajudei com algo correto. Na verdade, eu lamento pelo cara ter votado negativo e achar que vai mudar alguma coisa haha. Eu vou sair daqui com 23pt e vc com o problema resolvido, e o que o Downvote representa? Nada :D, seria melhor ele ter tentado alguma resposta melhor ou feito um cometário construtivo, é um voto jogado no lixo...